# CakePHP saving foreignKeys not working

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have 3 tables: Computers hasMany Brands, Brands belongsTo Computers and Parts. Now i have these fields in my Brands `description`,`computer_id`,`part_id`. I have the code below to save my data. It will save the description and part_id....But my computer_id does not save at all. 
Usually my URL written `http://192.168.6.253/computers/brands/add/1` where 1 is computer_id.

How will I save it? Im still beginner in this framework

Controller

```
public function add($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }
            //Assign value to link computer_id
            $data = $this->Brand->Computer->findById($id);
            $this->set('computers', $data);

            //assign select values to parts select
            $this->set('parts', $this->Brand->Part->find('list',
                array('fields' => array('description'))));


            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Brand->create();
                if ($this->Brand->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'table/'.$id));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
                }
            }

        }
```

View

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Brand');
echo $this->Form->input('part_id',array('empty'=>' '));
echo $this->Form->input('description');
echo $this->Form->input('computer_id',array('type'=>hidden));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: I will further read it, but can you help me find what did i done wrong with my code?

Comment: Check your data formatting, and swap from `save()` to `saveAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not requiring to send the computer id through the form since it's a url param... you can adjust your add function like this

```
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->request->data['Brand']['computer_id'] = $id; //manually add the id to the request data object
            $this->Brand->create();
            if ($this->Brand->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'table/'.$id));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
            }
        }
```

That's a very basic way of doing it without checking for data integrity, anyone could easily change the param to a 2, but it conforms with your current setup.

Comment: `$this->request->data['Brand']['computer_id'] = $id;` saves me, i never thought i can do that, thank you man...